# Cgo: undefined reference to [C function]

Tags: go, cgo

I'm running a go program in a docker container (`golang:1.18-bullseye`).

I haev tried running it both with `go run main.go` and `go run .`

My code looks likes this, both header files are located in the `Include` directory given in the CFLAGS:

```golang
/*
#cgo LDFLAGS: -Lvendor/MyCoolLibrary/1.14.2/Bin/Linux/libSDK-Linux-Shipping.so
#cgo CFLAGS: -I vendor/MyCoolLibrary/1.14.2/Include/
#include "my_cool_sdk.h"
#include "my_cool_logging.h"*/
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "runtime"
)

func main() {
ret := C.MyCoolFunc()
}
```

When I run this code, I get this error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: $WORK/b001/_x002.o: in function `_cgo_6bb9bcf96ac6_Cfunc_MyCoolFunc':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:110: undefined reference to `MyCoolFunc'
```

How can I fix this?

Edit: I changed the header to:

```
/*
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR}/vendor/MyCoolLibrary/1.14.2/Bin/Linux/libSDK-Linux-Shipping.so -lSDK-Linux-Shipping
#cgo CFLAGS: -I ${SRCDIR}/vendor/MyCoolLibrary/1.14.2/Include/
#include "my_cool_sdk.h"
#include "my_cool_logging.h"*/
```

and ran `go build -x .` and this is the output:

```
WORK=/tmp/go-build1175764972
mkdir -p $WORK/b001/
cd /home/helloworld
TERM='dumb' CGO_LDFLAGS='"-g" "-O2" "-L/home/helloworld/vendor/MyCoolLibrary/1.14.2/Bin/Linux/libSDK-Linux-Shipping.so" "-lSDK-Linux-Shipping"' /usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/cgo -objdir $WORK/b001/ -importpath go-sandbox -- -I $WORK/b001/ -g -O2 -I ./vendor/MyCoolLibrary/1.14.2/Include/ ./main.go
cd $WORK
gcc -fno-caret-diagnostics -c -x c - -o /dev/null || true
gcc -Qunused-arguments -c -x c - -o /dev/null || true
gcc -fdebug-prefix-map=a=b -c -x c - -o /dev/null || true
gcc -gno-record-gcc-switches -c -x c - -o /dev/null || true
cd $WORK/b001
TERM='dumb' gcc -I /home/helloworld -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK/b001=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -I ./ -g -O2 -I /home/helloworld/vendor/MyCoolLibrary/1.14.2/Include/ -o ./_x001.o -c _cgo_export.c
TERM='dumb' gcc -I /home/helloworld -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK/b001=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -I ./ -g -O2 -I /home/helloworld/vendor/MyCoolLibrary/1.14.2/Include/ -o ./_x002.o -c main.cgo2.c
TERM='dumb' gcc -I /home/helloworld -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK/b001=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -I ./ -g -O2 -I /home/helloworld/vendor/MyCoolLibrary/1.14.2/Include/ -o ./_cgo_main.o -c _cgo_main.c
cd /home/helloworld
TERM='dumb' gcc -I . -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK/b001=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -o $WORK/b001/_cgo_.o $WORK/b001/_cgo_main.o $WORK/b001/_x001.o $WORK/b001/_x002.o -g -O2 -L/home/helloworld/vendor/MyCoolLibrary/1.14.2/Bin/Linux/libSDK-Linux-Shipping.so -lSDK-Linux-Shipping
# go-sandbox
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDK-Linux-Shipping
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: How exactly do you "run this code"? I mean, do you use `go run`?

Comment: `go run main.go` or `go run .`

Comment: Does `go build` runs OK in the same directory? Also: the `-L` flag in your `LDFLAGS` definition is passed a relative pathname to a file while it's supposed to (augment) the list of search paths to find libraries passed to the linker via the `-l` (small letter el) command-line option—please refer to the `ld(1)` manual page. Hence I think the reason is simple: the linker fails to link in your library and hence a symbol it is supposed to export is not found.

Comment: Also: please never ever use `go run` at least you are 100% confident it is needed; use `go build`/`go install`, then run the resulting executable image file. The exact reasoning is a bit too long to expain; for short, Go is not a scripting language—at least in its stock implementation which you're apparently using.

Comment: Running `go build` with the `-x` command-line option produces copious output which contains calls to all the tools involved in creating the resulting executable, and their output. Consider using it to see what might have gone wrong with the build process. Also you could use a tool such as `nm` or `objdump` to verify that your `.so` library file indeed exports that `MyCoolFunc` symbol. (Well, for `.so` files you supposedly should use `lld`.)

Comment: @kostix I have used `lld` just to be sure, and can confirm the functions are there as expected. Notes taken on `go run` though, I had no idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce and fix this. There are also some additional gotchas. Start by just focusing on running `go build`:

Ok so the go compiler has found the header file, but cannot find the shared library. I think you modified your code for the question slightly and this is not an issue, but the path for `-L` in `LDFLAGS` has to be either:

- relative to the source directory using `${SRCDIR}`
- an absolute path
- avoid this entirely and leverage pkg-config
  I just used the relative directory containing the `so` file as my argument for `-L`.

Ok, that aside, you must also give a `-l` argument in LDFLAGS to find the file in the paths you pointed to (IE: `libvendera.so` needs `-lvendora`).

Once `go build` works you have an application that [still needs the know where](https://3.5.%20Installing%20and%20Using%20a%20Shared%20Library) the `so` file is to run (so hence a shared library). To do this you will likely need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and point to the directory containing the `so` file much like you did with `-L`.

Comment: Ok! (Disclosure: I did not edit the file header in any way. main.go is on the same level as vendor) - So essentially I need to point it at the `.so` library 3 times? Once with `-L`, once with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and once with `-lmylibrary`?

Comment: Then you should use the `${SRCDIR}` special variable:  `// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR}/libs -lfoo` to reference ./libs/libfoo.so. [Reference](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/cgo#:~:text=//%20%23cgo%20LDFLAGS%3A%20%2DL%24%7BSRCDIR%7D/libs%20%2Dlfoo)

Comment: Cool. when it comes to the `-l` argument, how do you know the name to use? I tried `-llibSDK-Linux-Shipping` and `-lSDK-Linux-Shipping` and it claims it can't find either

Comment: Usually you omit the `lib` prefix. Please try building with the `-x` command-line option and see what `gcc` outputs.

Comment: @kostix  I have added it to the Question ^

Comment: @JessicaChambers, you consistently miss what we're saying about what kind of pathnames the `-L` command-line option to the linker accepts ;-) It adds the indicated _directory_ to the list to look up the libs listed via the `-l` command line-option.

Comment: try `#cgo LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR}/vendor/MyCoolLibrary/1.14.2/Bin/Linux -lSDK-Linux-Shipping`

Comment: Oh whoops, sorry for being dense  That seems to have done the trick, thanks!